# How to work out if contour has moved away from being against an edge in Python/OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, logic

I'm creating a tracking system using a couple different techniques, MOSSE being one of them, I've got bounding boxes based on contours from background subtraction - I'm trying to work out the best way to get my Contours that will be on the screen to know if they have moved away from being against the image boundary (even a pixel away from the border edge), so I can then use that as the bounding box to start a MOSSE tracking from.

[image: Imgur]

I'm currently looping through contours, and need to check each contour against the arguments above.

I've thought about using pointPolygonTest and creating a contour for the entire area of the frame, checking whether the contour is inside this (no points touching the border). But can't seem to work out how to create a contour for the entire frame, plus this would probably be very inefficient.

```py
while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    contour, heir = cv2.findContours(fgmask, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)


    for cnt in contour:
        # and so on ...
        # This is where I will check the contour if it is touching frame boundary/edge
```

The outcome should be that if a contours edge is NOT touching the border (no pixel(s) gap between), I will get output informing me of this so I can add bounding boxes for MOSSE - this should happen for every contour in the frame.

If I haven't provided enough detail, or you need clarification, please feel free to comment, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution, using the contours as you suggested.

I've used the [OpenCV Wrapper library](https://github.com/anbergem/opencv_wrapper) to simplify the rectangle and contains stuff. It's not too hard to convert to normal OpenCV and Numpy, just a little tedious.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import opencv_wrapper as cvw

image = cv.imread("path/to/image")
gray = cvw.bgr2gray(image)
thresh = cvw.threshold_otsu(gray)

# Returns Contour object
contours = cvw.find_external_contours(thresh)

# Create a rectangle representing the boundary 1 pixel in.
boundary = cvw.Rect(1, 1, image.shape[1] - 2, image.shape[0] - 2)

for contour in contours:
    # Returns a Rect object
    rect = contour.bounding_rect
    if (
        rect.tl not in boundary
        or rect.tr not in boundary
        or rect.bl not in boundary
        or rect.br not in boundary
    ):
        continue

    # Create tracker
    cvw.rectangle(image, rect, cvw.Color.RED, 1)

cv.imshow("Image", np.hstack([image, cvw.gray2bgr(thresh)]))
cvw.wait_key(0)
```

Disclosure: I'm the author of OpenCV Wrapper.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, I'm going to give this a try now and tell you how it goes! Thank you for looking at this for me.

Comment: Marked as answer, i've got no issue with using other libraries - and this seems to really simplify a lot of problems with OpenCV! Thank you Andreas!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use floodfilling to clear all the edges of white pixels. When you find your contours after, you will be guaranteed that they are inside the frame. I used this code once to accomplish just that.

It is likely not the best solution, but a solution none the less.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# Image will then be binary, either 0 or 255. 
def floodfill_edges(image):
    where = np.where(image[:, 0] == 255)
    while where[0].size > 0:
        x, y = 0, where[0][0]
        cv.floodFill(image, None, (x, y), 0)
        where = np.where(image[:, 0] == 255)

    where = np.where(image[:, -1] == 255)
    while where[0].size > 0:
        x, y = image.shape[1] - 1, where[0][0]
        cv.floodFill(image, None, (x, y), 0)
        where = np.where(image[:, -1] == 255)

    where = np.where(image[0, :] == 255)
    while where[0].size > 0:
        x, y = where[0][0], 0
        cv.floodFill(image, None, (x, y), 0)
        where = np.where(image[0, :] == 255)

    where = np.where(image[-1, :] == 255)
    while where[0].size > 0:
        x, y = where[0][0], image.shape[0] - 1
        cv.floodFill(image, None, (x, y), 0)
        where = np.where(image[-1, :] == 255)

    return image
```

I'm not sure about efficiency, so you'll have to test this.